# How to delete label style saved in ArcView?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, style

The answer to my question may be very simple, but I can't seem to find it myself with online searches

I have symbology and text/label styles (etc) that I've saved for easy access when I'm working on a Map.  This is mostly for reasons of consistency.    If I wanted to delete one, how would I go about accomplishing this?

EXAMPLE (see image below):  Highlighted in yellow, are duplicate label styles I saved at some point.  I want to do some house cleaning.  How do I delete one of them (for dummies please)?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ArcMap, Go to the Customize menu, click Style Manager. You will see a style on the left called "Dano". Under that, any categories which contain custom symbols, labels, etc. you've made will appear as a yellow folder. Click the one you're concerned with and you'll see your custom symbols on the right. Right-click to delete any you don't want.

[image]

If your "Dano" style doesn't appear in the style manager, you can turn it on using the "Styles..." button.

Comment: Thank you "VERY" much Dan C. I was already in the process of doing exactly what you've suggested about 1/2 hour ago (based on what I was reading on the ESRI site). The window on the right (in the image you posted) was not showing up when style manager opened at my end - couldn't see the objects at all.  I just had to make the window wider and adjust the right pane so the objects were visible to me. I could not figure out why what I was seeing did not match what they were showing on the ESRI site. Many thanks!!! I knew it was something simple I was overlooking.